# How to describe Gender formally?

Tags: formality, political-correctness

For a User Interface of an Information System, options for selecting the Gender is to be given:

Not known

Male

Female

Male - TransGender

Female - TransGender

Is *Enuch* can be included; as an appropriate (formal) word, which can describe an Individual -neither male nor female? Any other word? Like Third-Gender or something?

Suggestions for all the words are welcome.

Comment: I would go with "other".

Comment: Why do you care about this question at all? Are you selling condoms or pads? Or you want to calculate the share of transgenders?

Comment: @Rusty Core For the Healthcare Information System

Comment: If you want to know whether your customer needs a condom or a tampon, you need to ask about biological sex, not about gender, which is a social role.

Comment: @Rusty Core I will surely ascertain which should be used? - Biological Sex seems more appropriate than Gender as per your comment. Please note that English is my third language, practically never got a chance to learn it till I crossed 12 Level Schooling.

Comment: Whatever you do, you should be aware that "eunuch" does not mean "neither male nor female". A eunuch is a castrated male. The word you perhaps want is "hermaphrodite" - but I would be flabbergasted to see it on a questionnaire or application form.

Comment: This is one of the few legitimate cases when asking about sex makes sense, still I might have rephrased it as "Requires services specific for men" and "Requires services specific for women" and making them non-mutually-exclusive, if I was really interested in serving customers, not in gathering statistics. But what do I know, today you come in with toothache, tomorrow you come with water broken. I digress. I suppose, as an information system developer it is not your task to come up with these questions, you need your product manager to provide you with clear specs. Unless you are the manager.

Comment: This is a very politically loaded subject these days. The right terms really depend on the context where the response will be used. The organizations using the data should be best situated to tell you what selections they need.

Comment: Why do people have to be given 'options' at all ? Why can't you just ask them what gender they are and let them put in what they think they are ?

Comment: @NigelJ This is for Computer System. Wanted to give an exhaustive list of options. People can use any one of the options. The System will process further based on the option selected. Given a choice user can input many variants, typo mistakes etc. In that case, the System can't go ahead further for processing which is mapped with the given options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for a Healthcare Information System, please verify whether the question refers to biological sex or gender. There is not enough information here to determine whether the question here is to determine a biological sex for medical reasons, or if it is a simple questionnaire for, say, a patient intake process, where gender would apply.

This being said, the standard for referring to specifically gender is different in different countries, but in most English-speaking locations, the norm is to ask: ***Male, Female, Other, Decline to State***

If your aim is to take a more "progressive" role with gender, you may want to try: ***Cisgender Male, Cisgender Female, Transgender Male, Transgender Female, Other, Decline to State***

Do bear in mind that the term *cisgender* is not currently part of the common vocabulary, and many dictionaries may not yet have an entry for this word. It is used to describe a person whose assigned gender and their biological sex are aligned.

Answer (score 0):

**[Intersex](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/intersex)** is the correct term to describe someone whose sex characteristics are not completely male or female.

'Intersex' does not describe the gender of the individual, only their sexual characteristics.

At one point 'congenital eunuchs' was a term for intersex people, but that [is no longer commonly used](http://Intersex).